# Angular 2 .angular-cli.json adding new files issue

Tags: angular

I'm facing some issues when i want to add my custom folder for a static json file.It's nothing special but i'd like to solve this.

[image: directory structure]

I'm developing a simple app that gets some data from the json,it's just for testing purposes.

And I'm having some problems with **.angular-cli.json** when i add a new folder to the

```
 "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "app/statics"
      ],
```

I'm unable to access it, but when i simply add my file to **assets**(folder) it works.Why?How can i set a path for my custom folder?

Is there something required to be done in the console to rebuild some stuff?
Thanks

Comment: So, what is the structure of your project (i.e. where do you put the file), what is the structure of the dist folder after `ng build` (i.e. where does the file end up being copied by the CLI), what is the code trying to load this JSON, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I don't know why do i have to explain it so detailed but okay.The static json file is in src/app/static/json-file.The dist folder is in the default place in the project root.The statics folder is in the same folder as assets,and i want to include the statics folder that it can be accessed as the assets folder.Thats it.

Comment: `assets` is inside `src`, `statics` is in `src/app` - therefore I'd guess you need to put `app/statics` in the config.

Comment: Therefore you guessed wrong.I don't know why people just post randomly stuff.Like test before you say anything ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to build the project, and in my **dist** folder i see the wanting folder.So after terminating the terminal and serving it again it worked.Hope it can help...And not like me to spend 2h searching for this dumb answer.....
Enjoy